# Proper folders structure for web application

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, war

I have a question - I created a war-package of the web-application (using Maven). The archive includes everything excepting jsp-files and resources. I know that Maven tracks only `src/main/resorces` and the proper solution is to keep jsp/css/xml in this directory. I develop in IntellijIdea and it has another folders structure for web-application. All the java-files are stored under `src/main/java` and jsp/css/xml are under `web/resources` and `web/WEB-INF`.

The question is where I have to store all resource files when developing? The idea to put them under `src/main/resorces` doesn't seem to me elegant because default folders structures is dislocated. I hope that I described my problem intelligibly. Thank you for reply

(I can't attach screenshot because of reputation shortage, so here it is a link [enter link description here](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/27/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82_2015-01-27_220656.png))

Comment: [Maven standard folder structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: You aren't describing resources, you're describing webapp files. Resources are things like configuration files for spring. Files that are part of the user experience -- jsps, css, js, etc. go in the webapp folder (in a maven structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you find the `src/main/resources` path as inelegant. This is the default path for maven.

For web applications `src/main/webapp` is also used and you can put the jsp,html,... files there.

If you have another structure you can configure maven to take web resources from another path as well.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>resource2</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Examples [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) clarify the structure well enough.

Comment: But the JSP, CSS, HTML, JS etc are not *resources* in the sense of `src/main/resources`, having them bundled up in a jar on the classpath won't accomplish the goal here I don't believe

Comment: I would say that everything goes that works fine)) But I'm confused because IntellijIdea folders structure differs from Maven's one. (Idea is very circumspect and sophisticated and I can't understand why it has difference in structure)

Comment: @aime - Did you build the project using Maven's webapp archetype? ([Example](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/))

Comment: :-) Use the archetype and place the HTML, JSP, CSS, etc in the *webapps* folder

Comment: Ok, I'll do this in my next app)

Comment: Actually, you have to do it in this app if you want it to work. The user can't access css files stored in your resources directory, because they'll be compiled into your jar files. They *must* be in your war file, which is what the webapp folder is compiled into, in order for the user to have access to them. This isn't optional.

Answer (score 1):

You want `src/main/webapp` for static web resources (HTML, CSS, JS, etc.)

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html